# How to partly update the webpage in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have started learning react and nodejs, trying to build a pokemon webpage with nodejs and react using pokeapi.

I would like to get the basic information of a list of pokemons at first and then list them as cards.

I want to add a feature for each card so that when I click them, a modal(invisible by default) will show up with the detailed information of that clicked pokemon.

I do not know which pokemon would be picked in advance. So I guess I need to send a request back to the server ask the server to fetch the data for me. So how can I do that using react?

While I do not want to reload all of the web page cause then I would need to fetch data for all the pokemons once more. Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need much nodejs code since you have a restful api (pokeapi)

You also need to get familiar with basic react setup checkout 
https://www.google.is/search?q=first+react+app&oq=first+react+app

The basic setup would be something like this >>

You would start by getting a list of Pokemon.

1. Checkout fetch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

   fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=10')
   .then(response => {
   console.log(response)
   })
2. You would then list out the names of the Pokemon

   response.results.forEach(item => {
     console.log(item.name + ' ' + item.url);
   })
3. And then create a modal (check out https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal) that queries the URL corresponding to each pokemon

   fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/')
   .then(response => {
   // Code to open react-modal which displays the 'response'
   })